# Indexing error: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I'm trying to take certain data out of a tensor, but I get weird error. Here, I will try to generate the error:

```
a=np.random.randn(5, 10, 5, 5)
a[:, [1, 6], np.triu_indices(5, 0)[0], np.triu_indices(5, 0)[1]].shape
```

I get this error

> shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes

I'm not even doing any broadcasting! it is all slicing stuff.

What do I want? leave zeroth axis as is (get everything), get [1] and [6] from first axis, reshape the last two axes from [5, 5] to [15] by taking upper triangle elements only.

Comment: Only the 1st index is a slice, the rest are arrays that are broadcasted together to create a composite index on 3 dimensions.

Comment: So whats the intended result shape, (5,2,15)?

Comment: @hpaulj Exactly! that's the required shape. I managed to get it but in two stages. I failed to make it in one line

Comment: Show the 2 steps. It may be simpler.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57273662/901925 and its duplicate.

Comment: @hpaulj step one: tmp = a[:, :, np.triu_indices(5, 0)[0], np.triu_indices(5, 0)[1]]
Step two: a= tmp[:, [1, 6], ...]
 so basically I avoided mixed indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to extend the second axis indexing array to `2D`, so that it forms an *outer-plane* against the indices off `np.triu_indices`. Thus, it give us a `2D` grid of `mxn` array with `m` being the length of that second axis indexing array and `n` being the lengths of the `np.triu_indices` ones. So, essentially, the entire solution would simplify to something like this -

```
r,c = np.triu_indices(5, 0)
out = a[:, np.array([1, 6])[:,None], r, c]
```

Or feed in that extended version as a list, i.e. -

```
out = a[:, [[1],[6]], r, c]
```

We can also use a masking based one with `np.tri/np.triu`, which might be faster on larger arrays as we would skip creating all the integer indices, like so -

```
mask = ~np.tri(5, k=-1, dtype=bool)
out = a[:, np.array([1, 6])[:,None], mask]
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand this! so the problem is mixed indexing methods. If I do it in two steps, it works. step one: treat last two axes, get a new matrix, step two: treat axes number 1 simple by a[:, [1, 6], ...]
Can you expand on what's outer-plane?

Comment: @Alex Think of those as two vectors (in matrix notation) that are "outer" with respect to each other. So,  `np.array([1, 6])[:,None]` is a column vector and r,c are row vectors. So, when operated together, they form an outer-operation obliging the numpy-broadcasting to extract 2D blocks. You gotta read up on numpy.ix_ and numpy-broadcasting docs and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608029/ for more info.